# How does callback work in AngularJS call to REST service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am studying AngularJS and REST.  A code sample uses the word `callback` repeatedly in an authentication function. Is "callback" a keyword in JavaScript or Angular?  Or is `callback` just a custom variable created in this code?

How does `callback` work in the code below? Googling `callback` and AngularJS is not producing usable results.  [The code for the AngularJS module in question can be read at this link](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/modular/src/main/resources/static/js/auth/auth.js), which also contains all the code for the sample app.

Here is the module code itself:

```
angular.module('auth', []).factory( 'auth',

    function($rootScope, $http, $location) {

        enter = function() {
            if ($location.path() != auth.loginPath) {
                auth.path = $location.path();
                if (!auth.authenticated) {
                    $location.path(auth.loginPath);
                }
            }                   
        }

        var auth = {

            authenticated : false,

            loginPath : '/login',
            logoutPath : '/logout',
            homePath : '/',
            path : $location.path(),

            authenticate : function(credentials, callback) {

                var headers = credentials && credentials.username ? {
                    authorization : "Basic "
                            + btoa(credentials.username + ":"
                                    + credentials.password)
                } : {};

                $http.get('user', {
                    headers : headers
                }).success(function(data) {
                    if (data.name) {
                        auth.authenticated = true;
                    } else {
                        auth.authenticated = false;
                    }
                    callback && callback(auth.authenticated);
                    $location.path(auth.path==auth.loginPath ? auth.homePath : auth.path);
                }).error(function() {
                    auth.authenticated = false;
                    callback && callback(false);
                });

            },

            clear : function() {
                $location.path(auth.loginPath);
                auth.authenticated = false;
                $http.post(auth.logoutPath, {}).success(function() {
                    console.log("Logout succeeded");
                }).error(function(data) {
                    console.log("Logout failed");
                });
            },

            init : function(homePath, loginPath, logoutPath) {

                auth.homePath = homePath;
                auth.loginPath = loginPath;
                auth.logoutPath = logoutPath;

                auth.authenticate({}, function(authenticated) {
                    if (authenticated) {
                        $location.path(auth.path);
                    }
                })

                // Guard route changes and switch to login page if unauthenticated
                $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
                    enter();
                });

            }

        };

        return auth;

    });
```

### Additional information

Based on @okonyk's response, I am including code from a different module that calls the auth.authenticate() function:

```
$scope.login = function() {
    auth.authenticate($scope.credentials, function(authenticated) {
        if (authenticated) {
            //do some stuff
             $scope.error = false;
         } else { 
            $scope.error = true;
        }
    })
}
```

So how does the call from `login()` to `auth.authenticate($scope.credentials, function(authenticated)` work?  Is the `function(authenticated)` parameter sending a boolean that determines functionality inside `auth.authenticate()`? For example true might indicate to do the callback, while false might indicate note to do the callback, but it would help to have it explained.

[You can read the code in the sample app for the other module with the `login()` method by clicking on this link](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/modular/src/main/resources/static/js/navigation/navigation.js).

Answer (score 9):

[Here](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) is pretty good explanation:

> A callback function, also known as a higher-order function, is a function that is passed to another function (let’s call this other function “otherFunction”) as a parameter, and the callback function is called (or executed) inside the otherFunction. A callback function is essentially a pattern (an established solution to a common problem), and therefore, the use of a callback function is also known as a callback pattern.

`callback` is not a keyword, its just a name of parameter that is passed into the function, you can call it whatever you want (`callback` or `cb` is pretty common).

I'll try to explain it on example of super simplistic custom build callback function:

```
function useAsCallback(string){
  console.log("callback is being executed with passed parameter: " + string)
}

function main(param, callback){
  callback(param)
}

main(123456, useAsCallback)
```

if you run this, it would print: 
`callback is being executed with passed parameter: 123456`

Callback pattern is commonly used to handle JavaScript asynchronous behavior.

**EDIT:** more specific example:

**Talking about your code snippet...** lets say you'll inject your factory into controller.

Now you have `auth.authenticate` method exposed. You have to pass two parameters`(credentials, callback)`.

```
auth.authenticate({username: Joe, password: 123456}, function(authStatus){
  if(authStatus){
    console.log("Successfully authenticated")
  }else{
    console.log("Access denied")
  }
});
```

We just passed anonymous function as a `callback` parameter of our `auth.authenticate` method.

**EDIT:** responce to 'ADDITIONAL INFORMATION':

It looks like there might be some misunderstanding. You are asking:

> Is the function(authenticated) parameter sending a boolean that determines functionality inside auth.authenticate()

Thing is that, it is complete opposite: `auth.authenticate()` passes value into 'function(authenticated)', which is anonymous function. It happens at this point: `callback && callback(auth.authenticated);` - on `.success` or `callback && callback(false);` - on `.error`

Comment: OK, so then how does `callback` work in the code above? For example (among the rest of it) `callback && callback(false);`?

Comment: `callback && callback(false);` - is a shorthand conditional, which means: 'if callback was passed as parameter, than execute it while passing `false` as parameter'

Comment: Thank you. I added code at the end of the OP showing how the `auth.authenticate()` method is called, including a link to the calling code in the sample app on github. Are you willing to explain how the calling code from the `navigation.login()` function works with the `auth.authenticate()` function? Specifically, is it sending a true/false value as the second parameter? Where does the true/false come from?  And how does true or false influence the behavior of `auth.authenticate()`? This question has limited scope in terms of the github code, but I still feel like I only partially understand.

Comment: In your second snippet `auth.authenticate()` is similar to first one, it also takes two params`(credentials, callback)`.  It might be confusing which parameters `callback` takes... The answer is, it depends how `callback` is designed.

Comment: `callback` is called only once, as you see in `auth` factory, it might be called on `.success` or on `error` subsequently `true` or `false` is passed into `callback`. Welcome to JS callback world:)

Answer (score 0):

Basically writing something like

```
callback && callback(auth.authenticated);
```

or

```
callback && callback(false);
```

means that if that `callback` exists and then calls it.

simple example:

```
function foo () {
   console.log('foo');
   return 'Fighting foo!';
}

foo && foo();
```

It is just a language construct, a weird one and not a great practice for readability. This code also implies that the result of calling `foo()` should be valid but this is never handled. I'd use a simple `if` statement.